# How to add a plugin to jw-player?

Tags: javascript, flash, jwplayer

I've read about how to make JWPlayer plugins, and it is really easy. However, my main concern is what type of plugin should I create.

Here is what I want to accomplish:

I have some videos I need to edit. The backend programming is already created, but instead of having three selects telling

```
Start from: 00:00:00 
End at: 00:15:53
```

I want to add one scroll to JW Player with two limit the start and the end (pretty much what is done here: http://mp3cut.net/). Can I make this plugin with javascript or should I use action script?

Thanks for your help.

*Ps. If there is any plugin that make it already developed, will be great. I just couldn't find any...*

Comment: If you are using JW5, you might be able to just do this via the "start" and "duration" variables, since you can use these to specify the # in seconds to start (and end) a piece of content.

Comment: @EthanLongTail Thanks for your quick answer. We are using JW6, actually I think it is a beta release of the newest version. This is the version number: 6.3.3166 You guys sent it to us cause we were having some issues with the HLS compatibility. Could you gave me an example? (BTW, we have the pro version of the player)

Comment: Ah. We don't support start / duration with this version I'm afraid.

Comment: Because it is not the final version or because in JW6 you won't give that?

Comment: JW6 doesn't support these options because they didn't really work consistently across Flash/HTML5 modes previously.

Comment: So I supposed it wont be activated either. Am I right? In such case, is there any way I can accomplished that? I'm not an expert in jw-player...

Comment: I would advise using JW5 if you really need something like this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25726/discussion-between-abrahamsustaita-and-ethan-longtail)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have an IM handle for LongTail support.